# Good C++ directory and file library?

Tags: c++, windows, directory, search

I am making an application in C++ for windows, and one of its prime functions has to be directory and file io (searching, creating, etc). I basically want to be able to recursively search directories, and most of all be able to get the file names in a directory. Then I want to be able to get the directory names in the current directory.

In C#, it is a breeze to implement this functionality, but I am using C++. I tried using the windows API for this, but you know how the WIN API can be a pain in the neck and takes a million lines of code just to get a simple thing done. :P

So what are some good libs for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Try the [Boost.Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/).

Comment: I highly recommend this library. Very easy to use

Answer (score 3):

You can use SDK APIs Using [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx). They are simple :)

MSDN Example: [Listing the Files in a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(VS.85).aspx)

Apart from Boost suggested by @cjm, if you want to use MFC library:

[Recursive file search using C++ MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916973/recursive-file-search-using-c-mfc/916986#916986)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MFC'c [CFindFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618%28VS.80%29.aspx). [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/) has also a port of CFindFile, it's located in [atlmisc.h](http://wtl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wtl/trunk/wtl/include/atlmisc.h?view=markup)