# How can I detect the names of files in a folder in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, file-read

I have a folder that is containing text files (.txt). In my application I must read all files from this folder. But I don't know the names of these files and how many files in the folder. My application is C++ console application in MS VS 2013 without MFC support and without BOOST. Is there any function in Visual C++ that allows to detect the names of the files placed in specified folder and returns these file names? For example the name of the folder is SomeFolder. I'll be very much obliged to you for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of enumerating files within a folder such as WinAPI32 (FindFirstFile & FindNextFile) or MFC (CFileFind class).

The following are examples of either way:

[How to get list of files in a directory programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320573/how-to-get-list-of-files-in-a-directory-programatically)

[Recursive file search using C++ MFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916973/recursive-file-search-using-c-mfc)